# python copytree(src,dst) works only once

Tags: python

I have a working code:

```
import numpy as np
import os, sys
import shutil
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
import pandas as pd
shutil.rmtree('C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow')
os.mkdir('C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow')
fromDirectory = "C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/dakota/case"
x=16
fromDirectory=fromDirectory+str(x)
toDirectory = "C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow"
copy_tree(fromDirectory, toDirectory, update=1)
srednie()
shutil.rmtree(fromDirectory)
os.mkdir(fromDirectory)
copy_tree(toDirectory, fromDirectory, update=1)
```

where srednie() is some function that is working in the folder located 'C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow'

However, it works only once, i.e. if I change the x value in a loop it works only for the first counter.
Similarly, when I use

```
import numpy as np
import os, sys
import shutil
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
import pandas as pd
shutil.rmtree('C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow')
os.mkdir('C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow')
fromDirectory = "C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/dakota/case"
x=16
fromDirectory=fromDirectory+str(x)
toDirectory = "C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow"
copy_tree(fromDirectory, toDirectory, update=1)
srednie()
shutil.rmtree(fromDirectory)
os.mkdir(fromDirectory)
copy_tree(toDirectory, fromDirectory, update=1)

shutil.rmtree('C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow')
os.mkdir('C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow')
fromDirectory = "C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/dakota/case"
x=17
fromDirectory=fromDirectory+str(x)
toDirectory = "C:/users/nasa/desktop/opencv2/sklejanie_plikow"
copy_tree(fromDirectory, toDirectory, update=1)
srednie()
shutil.rmtree(fromDirectory)
os.mkdir(fromDirectory)
copy_tree(toDirectory, fromDirectory, update=1)
```

it works only for x=16.

I've read a comment here "Just bear in mind that copy_tree will fail if you call it twice for same set of args, and you've wiped the destination in the meantime. This is due to path caching in mkpath, see bugs.python.org/issue10948 – yacoob Dec 26 '16 at 0:15" which tells me that this is some typical problem, however I cant find any solution.

Any suggestions will be appreciated:)

Kind regards

Comment: I don't know if the ```shutil``` version of copytree might solve this issue. But try that

Comment: @kieranWood does not work, it tells that can not create file that already exists

Comment: Yeah its working;) I tried again and I just had to comment os.mkdir, because shutil.copytree(fromDirectory, toDirectory) creates a folder toDirectory itself